# How to post content in Linkedin using share Api from netsuite

Tags: linkedin-api

While using Share Api i got response as follows
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST /shares",
    "status": 403
}

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the fact that for the linkedin V2 API you need to become an linkedin partner. this can take up to a month befor you get a response.

> Partnering with LinkedIn provides you with additional API functionality & data access, increased call limits & dedicated support. Read more about our various Partner Programs and use cases and see if one is a match for your app. Applications are only accepted when we feel that they're providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn.

for more information see this link :

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs